# CKedit data not recognize in PHP validation Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, ckeditor

First of all I don`t really now how to explain this but its sounds complicated to me. It makes my brain broken and I really don`t know if there`s somebody that can help me to my problem with CKeditor.

My Controller Codes:

```
      public function reply_topic()
    {
        $this->load->helper('form');
        $this->load->library('form_validation');

        $this->form_validation->set_rules('comment', 'Comment Field Required', 'required');
        //$this->form_validation->set_rules('g-recaptcha-response', 'recaptcha validation', 'required|callback_validate_captcha');
        //$this->form_validation->set_message('validate_captcha', 'Please check the the captcha form');

        if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
        {
            $this->load_reply_to_topic_view($this->input->post('topic_id'));
        }
        else
        {
            $topic_id = $this->input->post('topic_id');
            $this->topic_model->postReplyTopic();
            echo '<div class="alert alert-success">'.lang_key('reply_submited').'</div>';
            $this->load_reply_to_topic_view($topic_id='');
        }
    }
```

This codes does not have a problem to begin with its working fine. But when I trying to submit the data it always come up with an error. 
Like the **comment field is empty** even though I already imputed a data to comment section - this error will come up if I am using a CKeditor. But if I only use ordinary textarea its really working fine.

```
<!-- Javascript -->
<script type="text/javascript">
CKEDITOR.replace( 'comment' );
</script>
```

And here is the code where the comment section appeared

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var loadUrl = '<?php echo base_url("threads/load_reply_to_topic_view/".$item['id']);?>';
    jQuery.post(
        loadUrl,
        {},
        function(responseText){
            jQuery('.reply-topic-form-holder').html(responseText);
            init_reply_topic_js();
        }
    );



function init_reply_topic_js()
{
    jQuery('#replytopic-form').submit(function(e){
            var data = jQuery(this).serializeArray();
            jQuery('.topic-loading').show();
            e.preventDefault();
            var loadUrl = jQuery(this).attr('action');
            jQuery.post(
                loadUrl,
                data,
                function(responseText){
                    jQuery('.reply-topic-form-holder').html(responseText);
                    jQuery('.alert-success').each(function(){
                        jQuery('#replytopic-form textarea').each(function(){
                            jQuery(this).val('');
                        });
                    });

                    jQuery('.topic-loading').hide();
                    init_reply_topic_js();
                }
            );
        });
}
</script>
```

Comment: Try asking Google, I asked - how to get data from ckeditor and Without regurgitating the answer from the website, here is the link - https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor4/docs/?mobile=/guide/dev_savedata

Comment: That really my problem is I don`t know how I will search it in google since I`m confuse regarding on this problem it makes me crazy.. By the way thanks for your response..

Comment: I gave you a link to look at. Did you look at it?

Comment: yes I did but I still coud’nt figure out what is the wrong.. Im still working on it even though it consume most of my time.. By the way thank you dude

Comment: look at `var data = CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.getData();` in the link @TimBrownlaw posted. My educated guess is that you have to add this to your data variable in post before sending via ajax.

Comment: I`m working on it but right now I disregarded this Issue its no rush if I can`t find any good solution on this I will find a remedy for this issue..

Comment: By the way dude just give an update its working now. @Alex helped me out.. and thanks also for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CK doesn't actually make use of the textarea field, it is just a 'placeholder' for it so to speak. So you have to make sure that the data in CK gets added to the textarea or you will get no data for that field when you post it via AJAX. When posting normally this is not a problem due to [autoUpdateElement](https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor4/docs/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config-cfg-autoUpdateElement).

Before `var data = jQuery(this).serializeArray();` add `CKEDITOR.instances.comment.updateElement();`. This will ensure that the internal markup of CK editor gets added to the textarea so it will populate the field before serializing the array.

Documentation on the method [here](https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor4/docs/#!/api/CKEDITOR.editor-method-updateElement).

```
jQuery('#replytopic-form').submit(function (e) {
    CKEDITOR.instances.comment.updateElement();
    var data = jQuery(this).serializeArray();
    jQuery('.topic-loading').show();
    e.preventDefault();
    var loadUrl = jQuery(this).attr('action');
    jQuery.post(
            loadUrl,
            data,
            function (responseText) {
                jQuery('.reply-topic-form-holder').html(responseText);
                jQuery('.alert-success').each(function () {
                    jQuery('#replytopic-form textarea').each(function () {
                        jQuery(this).val('');
                    });
                });
                jQuery('.topic-loading').hide();
                init_reply_topic_js();
            }
    );
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much dude its working now.. Awesome!.. By the way can you check my other concern about ck if it is ok to you..? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47763304/ckeditor-not-image-video-link-embed-and-many-others-not-working-in-modal